# How do I run a Python script on a set of JSON files?

Tags: python, json

I am writing a script that takes 2 JSON files which will just be a basic object of key/value pairs and compare the lengths of the files (number of keys) and well as if the keys are matching.

I will have an environment folder called `vars` which is where all of the JSON files will exist. I am able to run my script to compare one file to the config file, but I am wondering if there is a way to check each file in the `vars` folder one after another. i.e. I first go through the script for file1.json against config.json, return the desired result, then run the script for file2.json against config.json immediately afterwards. I am unsure of how I can go about this.

My project structure looks like this, where there will always be a config.json being compared against the rest of the JSON files:

```
├── .
│   ├── vars/
│   │   ├── file1.json
│   │   └-─ file2.json
|   |   |__ config.json
│   ├── main.py
```

Example of JSON files:

```
{
  "appSettings": {
    "FileOne": "file1.json"
    "Audience": "https://{}",
    "Domain": "url.com",
    "AuthKey": "1234",
    "AuthURL": "https://{}"
  }
}
-----------------------------
{
  "appSettings": {
    "FileTwo": "file2.json"
    "Audience": "https://{}",
    "Domain": "url.com",
    "AuthKey": "1234",
    "AuthURL": "https://{}"
  }
}
```

The goal is to load up these files and compare them as they should be identical. If I only have the 2 files in my `vars` folder (file1.json & config.json), the script works perfectly fine. If I was to add a second JSON file to compare (file2.json), it will only run against one of the files.

```
import os
import json

path = './vars'

def main():
    json_files = []
    param_config_file = ''

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if ('config' in file):
                param_config_file = file
            if (file.endswith('.json') and 'config' not in file):
                json_files.append(file)

    check_file_lengths(json_files, param_config_file)
    return check_setting_files(json_files, param_config_file)


def return_func_settings(func_files):
    app_settings = ''

    for file in func_files:
        f = open(f'{path}/{file}')
        app_settings = json.load(f)
    # print({'file_name': file, 'settings': app_settings['appSettings']})
    return {'file_name': file, 'settings': app_settings['appSettings']}


def return_config_settings(config_file):
    f = open(f'{path}/{config_file}')
    config_app_settings = json.load(f)

    return {'file_name': config_file, 'settings': config_app_settings['appSettings']}


def check_file_lengths(func_file, config):
    func_settings = return_func_settings(func_file)
    config_settings = return_config_settings(config)

    file = func_settings['file_name']
    config = config_settings['file_name']

    print(f"Checking '{file}' against '{config}'")

    if (len(func_settings['settings']) != len(config_settings['settings'])):
        print("WARNING: The file sizes are different! Debuging...")


def check_setting_files(json, config):
    missing_settings = []
    is_matching = False

    func_settings = return_func_settings(json)
    config_settings = return_config_settings(config)

    main_file, sub_file = '', ''
    if (len(func_settings['settings']) >= len(config_settings['settings'])):
        main_file = func_settings
        sub_file = config_settings
    else:
        main_file = config_settings
        sub_file = func_settings

    for app_setting in main_file['settings']:
        if (app_setting in sub_file['settings']):
            is_matching = True
        else:
            missing_settings.append(app_setting)
            print(
                f"App setting '{app_setting}' doesn't exist in {sub_file['file_name']}")
            is_matching = False

    if (is_matching):
        print(
            f"The app settings in '{main_file['file_name']}' are in line with '{sub_file['file_name']}'")
    else:
        raise Exception(
            f"App settings: {missing_settings} are missing in '{sub_file['file_name']}'")

main()
```

I put together a Repl to demonstrate what I'm trying to do: https://replit.com/@AlexWhitmore/python-stuff?v=1

Comment: In `return_func_settings`, you loop over `func_files` but overwrite `app_settings` at each iteration, so you're discarding everything you read except the last file.

Comment: you should have two object where one object contain the config file where other object have json file. then you can compare these object key value and change content of json object with other json file

Comment: Though please still reduce your problem to a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

using os.listdir, it is possible to iterate through files in a folder, and you can match the names to what you want to do

```
import os
 
# Get the list of all files and directories
path = "YOUR_PATH/vars"
dir_list = os.listdir(path)

# need to read from each file
for dir in dir_list:
    if dir == "file.json":
        # read content and do the thing
```